# Vertical alignment of display and image

Tags: vertical-alignment

[image]

is produced processing this file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{cases}
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7
  \end{cases}\qquad%
  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
\]
\end{document}
```

I'd like to vertically align the center of image and the center of the display, and I can do it using trial and error, like in

```
\raisebox{-0.92cm}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}
```

[image]

Can you help me and show me how the trial and error can be fully automated?

---

Doing as suggested by [David](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle)

*"replace `{-0.92cm` by `{-.5\height`"*

I get a good enough solution, as I have an alignment on the baseline (?) of the display.

I have to mention that, if the display contains a vertically asymmetric object (e.g., a continuous fraction) the result may appeal someone and displease some others.

[image]

Comment: replace `{-0.92cm` by `{-.5\height`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle your suggestion centers (I believe) to the baseline, and not to the actual math center.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes which looks best depends on the image  `{\dimexpr.5\baselineskp-\height`  or if you really want you can dig out the math axis from the font dimen of `\textfont2` if you use `example-image-a` with an exact centre line exact measurements work. if it is a picture of a cat, adjusting the offset by eye often helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{cases}
    1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7
  \end{cases}\qquad%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this does not produce the identical result obtained with `\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}`, since this `.5\height` approach centers relative to the baseline of `4`, rather than its math centerline, as shown here:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since you're not really making use of much of the `cases` machinery, I'd like to suggest that you employ a `matrix` environment to display the column vector on the left. I'd further like to suggest that you embed the `\includegraphics` directive on the right in a one-column `tabular` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}  % for 'matrix' env.
\usepackage{graphicx} % for '\includegraphics' macro

\begin{document}

\[
  \left\{ \begin{matrix}
     1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6\\7
  \end{matrix} \right.
  \qquad
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
  \end{tabular}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do it.

I add a sensible usage of `cases` (don't employ it if there is no side condition).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} % for solution number 4

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  f(x)=\begin{cases}
    1 & 0<x\le 1 \\
    2 & 1<x\le 2 \\
    3 & 2<x\le 3 \\
    4 & 3<x\le 4 \\
    5 & 4<x\le 5 \\
    6 & 5<x\le 6 \\
    7 & 6<x\le 7
  \end{cases}
  \qquad
  \raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  f(x)=\begin{cases}
    1 & 0<x\le 1 \\
    2 & 1<x\le 2 \\
    3 & 2<x\le 3 \\
    4 & 3<x\le 4 \\
    5 & 4<x\le 5 \\
    6 & 5<x\le 6 \\
    7 & 6<x\le 7
  \end{cases}
  \qquad
  \begin{array}{@{}c@{}}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\end{array}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  f(x)=\begin{cases}
    1 & 0<x\le 1 \\
    2 & 1<x\le 2 \\
    3 & 2<x\le 3 \\
    4 & 3<x\le 4 \\
    5 & 4<x\le 5 \\
    6 & 5<x\le 6 \\
    7 & 6<x\le 7
  \end{cases}
  \qquad
  \begin{gathered}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}\end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  f(x)=\begin{cases}
    1 & 0<x\le 1 \\
    2 & 1<x\le 2 \\
    3 & 2<x\le 3 \\
    4 & 3<x\le 4 \\
    5 & 4<x\le 5 \\
    6 & 5<x\le 6 \\
    7 & 6<x\le 7
  \end{cases}
  \qquad
  \includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=c]{example-image-a}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Even if it's essentially the same as (3), I'd avoid `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}`.

[image]

Note that in (1) the position is not really as expected.